# Semi-continuity and equality a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We consider for every $r\in \mathbb{R},$ two Borel functions $f_r:\mathbb{R}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $h_r:\mathbb{R}\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that for every $r\in \mathbb{R},f_r\leq h_r$ and $\lambda(\{f_r\neq h_r\})=0,\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

We suppose that for every $x\in \mathbb{R},$ the functions $r\to -f_r(x)$ and $r\to h_r(x)$ are upper semi-continuous.

Can we claim that for $\lambda$-almost every $x\in \mathbb{R},$ for all $r\in \mathbb{R},f_r(x)=h_r(x)$ (that is $\{x\in \mathbb{R},\exists r\in \mathbb{R},f_r(x)\neq h_r(x)\}$ is $\lambda$-negligeable)? Why?

I tried using Baire theorem to approximate by two monotone sequences of continuous functions $f^n_r,h^n_r$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't the hypothesis $\lambda( \{ f_r \neq h_r \}) =0$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ already implies that for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $f_r(x) = h_r(x)$ for $\lambda$-a.e?

Comment: $\lambda$-a.e should be before for every $r\in \mathbb{R},$ this is stronger!

Comment: We can't simply take the union over $r\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Are you required to prove that for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lambda(\{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon f_r(x) \neq h_r(x) \}) =0$?

Comment: No, the question is to prove that $\{x\in \mathbb{R},\exists r\in \mathbb{R},f_r(x)\neq h_r(x)\}$ is $\lambda$-negligeable